# Bullet Physics MultiSphereShape Usage

Tags: physics-engine, bulletphysics, rigid-bodies

1. I am posting here because I have not been successful in finding a helpful answer either directly on the Bullet Physics forum or any of those associated forums which have either ported the library [JBullet, BulletCS] or incorporated it in their own product [Blender, Panda3d]. Here it seems, at least if I can ask the question properly, the odds seem best of getting a helpful reply.
2. I want to simulate the rolling of dice. All the examples I can find seem content with using a Box shape.  Mine is an interest in children's games, not Las Vegas.  The defining difference, at least in my application, is that the dice [whether 6-sided, or something else, but let's just stick with 6-sided here] have 'kinder-gentler' rounded edges with no pointed corners.
3. It seems that btMultiSphereShape would be just perfect for me -- me being someone who does not have the knowledge to construct any complex shape from lower-level primitives, me being someone who hopes to use what is already built into the collision intelligence of the Bullet engine, not someone trying to engineer any new, exotic behavior.
4. With that preface I would really appreciate a succinct example of:

   a.  how to pass the arguments to the btMultiSphhereShape constructor;
    b.  how to configure the transform that needs to be passed to btDefaultMaotionState; and
    c.  how to set the localInertia.
5. I understand that this is a general-purpose library with classes that can support almost anything, but please, for a beginner, instead of discussions of those very nice attributes of a well-conceived toolkit, what would be most helpful to me [and I believe to many other users] would be a clear example of supplying those key properties to the necessary classes and methods to these specifics:

   a.  a six-sided die with equal dimensions, let's make the rounded cube about 2cm per side;
    b.  let's have the radius of the 'corners' a gentle 0.1.cm.
6. Now, one more request, please.  In order to observe the behavior of the die beginning with a simple 'drop', taking into account only forces due to gravity, please suggest a transform that will result in some kind of interesting tumbling result from a collision against the usual 'floor' example; in other words, it should impact the floor on a rounded corner.

Answer (score 1):

I used Bullet Physics on iOS devices to create a dice game. To get more realistic looking dice, I created a "RoundedCube" object which is just a cube with beveled edges. Here is the Objective-c code I wrote to create the verticies

```
//
//  Created by John Carter on 4/9/09.
//

#import "RoundedCube.h"


static const GLfloat voffset[] =
        {
        // Front Face (counterclockwise winding)
        +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f,
        -1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f,
        +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f,

        // Back Face (clockwise winding)
        +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,    
        -1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,
        +1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

        // Top Face (counterclockwise winding)
        -1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,

        // Bottom Face (clockwise winding)
        -1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        +1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f,
        +1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f,

        // Right Face (clockwise winding)
        +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f,
        +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f,
        +1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,

        // Left Face (counterclockwise winding)
        -1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f,
        -1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f,
        -1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f,
        };



// Private Methods
//
@interface RoundedCube()

- (void) computeRoundedCubeNormals;

@end



@implementation RoundedCube


- (void) dealloc
    {
    [super dealloc];
    }





- (void) computeRoundedCubeNormals
    {
    int i;

    xMinVertex = FLT_MAX;
    yMinVertex = FLT_MAX;
    zMinVertex = FLT_MAX;
    xMaxVertex = -FLT_MAX;
    yMaxVertex = -FLT_MAX;
    zMaxVertex = -FLT_MAX;

    for (i=0; i<vertexDataCount; i+=3)
        {
        if ( vertexData[i+0] < xMinVertex )
            xMinVertex = vertexData[i+0] ;
        if ( vertexData[i+1] < yMinVertex )
            yMinVertex = vertexData[i+1] ;
        if ( vertexData[i+2] < zMinVertex )
            zMinVertex = vertexData[i+2] ;

        if ( vertexData[i+0] > xMaxVertex )
            xMaxVertex = vertexData[i+0] ;
        if ( vertexData[i+1] > yMaxVertex )
            yMaxVertex = vertexData[i+1] ;
        if ( vertexData[i+2] > zMaxVertex )
            zMaxVertex = vertexData[i+2] ;
        }

    xVertexRange = fabs(xMaxVertex - xMinVertex);
    yVertexRange = fabs(yMaxVertex - yMinVertex);
    zVertexRange = fabs(zMaxVertex - zMinVertex);

    for (i=0; i<vertexDataCount; i+=9)
        {
        btVector3 V0 = btVector3( vertexData[i+0], vertexData[i+1], vertexData[i+2] );
        btVector3 V1 = btVector3( vertexData[i+3], vertexData[i+4], vertexData[i+5] );
        btVector3 V2 = btVector3( vertexData[i+6], vertexData[i+7], vertexData[i+8] );

        btVector3 delta1 = (V1) - (V0);
        btVector3 delta2 = (V2) - (V0);

        btVector3 vertexNormal = delta1.cross(delta2);
        vertexNormal = vertexNormal.normalize();

        if ( useAbsNormals )
            {
            vertexNormal = vertexNormal.absolute();
            }

        normalData[i+0] = vertexNormal[0];
        normalData[i+1] = vertexNormal[1];
        normalData[i+2] = vertexNormal[2];

        normalData[i+3] = vertexNormal[0];
        normalData[i+4] = vertexNormal[1];
        normalData[i+5] = vertexNormal[2];

        normalData[i+6] = vertexNormal[0];
        normalData[i+7] = vertexNormal[1];
        normalData[i+8] = vertexNormal[2];
        }
    }






- (void) addBeveledCorner:(int)bevelPlane At:(btVector3)bevelLocation Size:(btVector3)bevelSize Rotation:(double)rotationOrigin
    {
    btVector3 vertexPoint[6];
    double delta;
    double theta0;
    double theta1;
    double phi0;
    double phi1;
    int vp;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    delta = (double)M_PI_2 / (double)smoothFactor;

    // vertical segments
    //
    for( i=0; i<smoothFactor; i++)
        {
        theta0 = (double)i * (double)delta;
        theta1 = (double)(i+1) * (double)delta;

        if ( bevelPlane==1 )
            {
            theta0 += M_PI;
            theta1 += M_PI;
            }

        // horizontal segments
        //
        for( j=0; j<smoothFactor; j++)
            {
            phi0 = (double)j * (double)delta;
            phi1 = (double)(j+1) * (double)delta;

            phi0 += rotationOrigin;
            phi1 += rotationOrigin;

            if ( bevelPlane==1 )
                {
                phi0 += M_PI;
                phi1 += M_PI;
                }

            vp=0;

            if ( bevelPlane==0 )
                {
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*cos(phi0)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta0)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*sin(phi0)));
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*cos(phi1)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta0)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*sin(phi1)));
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*cos(phi1)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta1)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*sin(phi1)));

                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*cos(phi0)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta0)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*sin(phi0)));
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*cos(phi1)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta1)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*sin(phi1)));
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*cos(phi0)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta1)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*sin(phi0)));
                }
            else
                {
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*cos(phi0)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta0)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*sin(phi0)));
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*cos(phi1)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta1)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*sin(phi1)));
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*cos(phi1)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta0)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*sin(phi1)));

                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*cos(phi0)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta0)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta0)*sin(phi0)));
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*cos(phi0)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta1)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*sin(phi0)));
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*cos(phi1)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta1)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(sin(theta1)*sin(phi1)));
                }

            for ( k=0; k<6; k++ )
                {
                vertexData[coordinateElement++] = vertexPoint[k][0];
                vertexData[coordinateElement++] = vertexPoint[k][1];
                vertexData[coordinateElement++] = vertexPoint[k][2];

                colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[0];
                colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[1];
                colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[2];
                colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[3];
                }
            }
        }

    }







- (void) addBeveledEdge:(int)bevelPlane At:(btVector3)bevelLocation Size:(btVector3)bevelSize Rotation:(double)rotationOrigin
    {
    btVector3 vertexPoint[6];
    double origin;
    double delta;
    double theta0;
    double theta1;
    int vp;
    int i;
    int j;

    delta = (double)(M_PI_2) / (double)smoothFactor;

    for ( i=0; i<smoothFactor; i++ )
        {
        theta0 = (double)i * (double)delta;
        theta1 = (double)(i+1) * (double)delta;

        theta0 += rotationOrigin;
        theta1 += rotationOrigin;

        origin = (double)0.0;
        vp=0;

        switch( bevelPlane )
            {
            case 0:
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0], bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(sin(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta0+origin)) );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0], bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(sin(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta1+origin)) );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]-bevelSize[0], bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(sin(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta1+origin)) );

                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]-bevelSize[0], bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(sin(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta0+origin)) );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0], bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(sin(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta0+origin)) );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]-bevelSize[0], bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(sin(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta1+origin)) );
                break;

            case 1:
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1], bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta0+origin)) );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[1]-bevelSize[1], bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta1+origin)) );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1], bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta1+origin)) );

                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[1]-bevelSize[1], bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta0+origin)) );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[1]-bevelSize[1], bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta1+origin)) );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1], bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2]*btScalar(cos(theta0+origin)) );
                break;

            case 2:
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2] );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2] );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[2]-bevelSize[2] );

                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[2]-bevelSize[2] );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta0+origin)), bevelLocation[2]+bevelSize[2] );
                vertexPoint[vp++] = btVector3( bevelLocation[0]+bevelSize[0]*btScalar(sin(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[1]+bevelSize[1]*btScalar(cos(theta1+origin)), bevelLocation[2]-bevelSize[2] );
                break;
            }


        for ( j=0; j<6; j++ )
            {
            vertexData[coordinateElement++] = vertexPoint[j][0];
            vertexData[coordinateElement++] = vertexPoint[j][1];
            vertexData[coordinateElement++] = vertexPoint[j][2];

            colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[0];
            colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[1];
            colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[2];
            colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[3];
            }
        }
    }


- (RoundedCube *) Length:(GLfloat)initLength Width:(GLfloat)initWidth Height:(GLfloat)initHeight Bevel:(GLfloat)initBevel SmoothFactor:(int)initSmoothFactor RGBA:(GLubyte *)initRGBA AbsNormals:(BOOL)initUseAbsNormals
    {
    int i;

    smoothFactor = initSmoothFactor;
    useAbsNormals = initUseAbsNormals;

    shape = (id *)self;
    length = initLength;
    width = initWidth;
    height = initHeight;
    bevel = initBevel;

    coordinateElement=0;
    colorElement=0;

    for (i=0; i<24; i++)
        rgba[i] = initRGBA[i];

    vertexCount = 36 + (12 * 6 * smoothFactor) + (smoothFactor * smoothFactor * 6 * 8);


    modelType = MT_BOX;
    constructMode = GL_TRIANGLES;
    showColorAndTexture = NO;
    vertexDataCount = vertexCount * 3;
    colorDataCount = vertexCount * 4;
    normalDataCount = vertexCount * 3;

    [self setSurfaceToDefault];

    vertexData = (GLfloat *)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexDataCount);
    memset(vertexData, (unsigned int)0, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexDataCount);

    normalData = (GLfloat *)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * normalDataCount);
    memset(normalData, (unsigned int)0, sizeof(GLfloat) * normalDataCount);

    colorData = (GLubyte *)malloc(sizeof(GLubyte) * colorDataCount);
    memset(colorData, (unsigned int)0, sizeof(GLubyte) * colorDataCount);

    int cubeSide;
    int trianglesPerSide;
    int pointsPerTriangle;

    for ( cubeSide=0; cubeSide<6; cubeSide++ )
        {
        for ( trianglesPerSide=0; trianglesPerSide<2; trianglesPerSide++ )
            {
            for ( pointsPerTriangle=0; pointsPerTriangle<3; pointsPerTriangle++ )
                {
                switch( cubeSide )
                    {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                        vertexData[coordinateElement+0] = voffset[coordinateElement+0] * (length - bevel);
                        vertexData[coordinateElement+1] = voffset[coordinateElement+1] * (width - bevel);
                        vertexData[coordinateElement+2] = voffset[coordinateElement+2] * height;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                        vertexData[coordinateElement+0] = voffset[coordinateElement+0] * (length - bevel);
                        vertexData[coordinateElement+1] = voffset[coordinateElement+1] * width;
                        vertexData[coordinateElement+2] = voffset[coordinateElement+2] * (height - bevel);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                        vertexData[coordinateElement+0] = voffset[coordinateElement+0] * length;
                        vertexData[coordinateElement+1] = voffset[coordinateElement+1] * (width - bevel);
                        vertexData[coordinateElement+2] = voffset[coordinateElement+2] * (height - bevel);
                        break;
                    }

                coordinateElement += 3;

                colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[(cubeSide*4) + 0]; // 1 RGBA color set per side
                colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[(cubeSide*4) + 1]; // 1 RGBA color set per side
                colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[(cubeSide*4) + 2]; // 1 RGBA color set per side
                colorData[colorElement++] = rgba[(cubeSide*4) + 3]; // 1 RGBA color set per side
                }
            }
        }


    [self addBeveledEdge:2 At:btVector3((length-bevel), (width-bevel), 0) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,height-bevel) Rotation:(double)0.0];
    [self addBeveledEdge:2 At:btVector3(-(length-bevel), (width-bevel), 0) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,height-bevel) Rotation:(double)-M_PI_2];
    [self addBeveledEdge:2 At:btVector3(-(length-bevel), -(width-bevel), 0) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,height-bevel) Rotation:(double)-M_PI];
    [self addBeveledEdge:2 At:btVector3((length-bevel), -(width-bevel), 0) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,height-bevel) Rotation:(double)M_PI_2];

    [self addBeveledEdge:1 At:btVector3((length-bevel), 0, (height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,width-bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)0.0];
    [self addBeveledEdge:1 At:btVector3(-(length-bevel), 0, (height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,width-bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)-M_PI_2];
    [self addBeveledEdge:1 At:btVector3(-(length-bevel), 0, -(height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,width-bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)-M_PI];
    [self addBeveledEdge:1 At:btVector3((length-bevel), 0, -(height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,width-bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)M_PI_2];

    [self addBeveledEdge:0 At:btVector3(0, (width-bevel),  (height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(length-bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)0.0];
    [self addBeveledEdge:0 At:btVector3(0, -(width-bevel),  (height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(length-bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)-M_PI_2];
    [self addBeveledEdge:0 At:btVector3(0, -(width-bevel),  -(height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(length-bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)-M_PI];
    [self addBeveledEdge:0 At:btVector3(0, (width-bevel), -(height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(length-bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)M_PI_2];

    [self addBeveledCorner:0 At:btVector3((length-bevel), (width-bevel), (height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)0.0];
    [self addBeveledCorner:0 At:btVector3((length-bevel), (width-bevel), -(height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)-M_PI_2];
    [self addBeveledCorner:0 At:btVector3(-(length-bevel), (width-bevel), (height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)M_PI_2];
    [self addBeveledCorner:0 At:btVector3(-(length-bevel), (width-bevel), -(height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)M_PI];

    [self addBeveledCorner:1 At:btVector3((length-bevel), -(width-bevel), (height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)0.0];
    [self addBeveledCorner:1 At:btVector3((length-bevel), -(width-bevel), -(height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)-M_PI_2];
    [self addBeveledCorner:1 At:btVector3(-(length-bevel), -(width-bevel), (height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)M_PI_2];
    [self addBeveledCorner:1 At:btVector3(-(length-bevel), -(width-bevel), -(height-bevel)) Size:btVector3(bevel,bevel,bevel) Rotation:(double)M_PI];

    [self computeRoundedCubeNormals];

    return self;
    }
```

@end

If you have an iOS device you can see an example of how this looks in my free app [Amazing Dice HD on iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amazing-dice-hd/id384365014?mt=8)

Comment: Thank you so much John for posting complete rather than snippited code, it makes things so much more clear.

Comment: Thank you so much John for posting complete rather than snippited code, it makes things so much more clear.  That said, your beautiful shape, I think [I don't have access to an IOS device], is an improved visual object.  How does your RoundedCube class integrate with the Bullet classes?  Does an instance of your class get passed to a constructor for a RigidBody somewhere along the line?  Can you show me how your dice get mass, inertia, tension, motion -- whatever is required to interact with the physical world?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've worked with Bullet yet. They have a fantastic suit of examples you can compile that will answer all of your questions

Comment: Actually, I've spent a week trying to make this work in Bullet; that was the reason for the request. I've been trying to accomplish the desired result in BasicDemo.cpp using btMultiSphere, but I obviously don't get it. By passing in eight position and radi values, I get a cube with nice little balls at the vertices. As contrasted with your beveled edges that is obviously less esthetically nice, but my questions have to do with the falling, rolling, colliding behavior, so I was hoping to learn how you actually use your very handsome RoundedCubes.

Comment: All of the physics (falling, rolling, etc) is done by Bullet. You create a bullet object and add it to the world. Then you create your Open/GL object and draw it at the location and orientation of your bullet object. Every call to the bullet world step advances your physical world and all the objects in it by whatever time increment you define. After the bullet world step returns, you get the 3D coordinates and orientation (yaw,pitch,roll) of each object that Bullet is simulation and you draw that with your Open/GL models

Comment: Again, John, thank you, I know how to apply the current transform of the RigidBody to the MultiSphereShape, what you have not said, and is not indicated from the code you kindly posted was: a.) what specific RigidBody you use, and b.) how you configure the dimensions of the RigidBody to come as close as possible to conforming to the dimensions of your RoundedCube. Do you create a MultiSphereShape to handle the physics of your cube?  If so, could you please let me know how you create/configure that BulletPhysics object so that, as closely as possible, its collisions.

Comment: Oh, sorry...OK I'm just using a simple btBoxShape() for the physical object. The graphical representation is only slightly beveled on the edges so it doesn't affect the physics enough for a simulation like mine

Comment: Sorry to make you do so much work.  If you go to Wikipedia's entry for Dice and look at the middle row of examples in the Construction section you will see about the degree of rounding that I have on my equivalent to your RoundedCube -- it is enough different from the behavior of a btBoxShape to make me want to improve on the physics.  BTW, there will be variations of non-cubics -- die with 5, 7, 10 or 12 sides, for example.  So, I hope to learn enough to make the 6-rounded-side case work, then I might be able to extrapolate to those other configurations.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I've posted another block of code from some old projects of mine. I added all the dependancies as well so it quite a bit. The method that may help is the MeshObject where I basically take the vertices of a model to create a corresponding bullet triangle mesh object

Comment: Yes, John, it is very helpful to see the code that links the physical object to the visual one. With far less experience in use of the Bullet library, I can, nonetheless, easily read your nicely organized code, and recognize your implementation of the necessary code.  So, did you find btBvhTriangleMeshShape better than btBoxShape as a 'container' for the modelling of the behavior of your RoundedCube, or were they just different applications with different requirements?  I guess, in both cases, the physical container still had clean 90-degree edges, so I guess rolling was about the same?

Comment: I wrote the function and played with it in testing but never used it in my apps because the btBvhTriangleMeshShape was just too slow for an iOS app so I had to stick with basic shapes

Answer (score 1):

I've posted another block of code from some old projects of mine that may get you going in the right direction. I added all the dependancies as well so its a lot. The method that may help is the MeshObject where I basically take the vertices of a model to create a corresponding bullet object for adding to the physics world

```
//
//  BulletEngine.h
//  Created by John Carter on 4/9/09.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "btBulletDynamicsCommon.h"
#include "Matrix.h"

@interface BulletEngine : NSObject
    {
    btScalar cycles;            // number of clocktick cycles to run with each call
    btScalar clockTick;     // 0.016 = 1/60th of a second
    }

@property (readwrite) btScalar cycles;
@property (readwrite) btScalar clockTick;

- (void) timeStep:(UIAccelerationValue *)accelerationValue;
- (void) timeStep;
- (void) addConstraint:(btTypedConstraint *)hinge disableCollisionsBetweenLinkedBodies:(BOOL)linkcrash;
- (void) releaseConstraints;

@end



//
//  BulletEngine.m
//  Created by John Carter on 4/9/09.
//
#import "BulletEngine.h"
#import "PhysicsObject.h"

// Private Methods
//
@interface BulletEngine()

@end


@implementation BulletEngine

@synthesize cycles;
@synthesize clockTick;

static btCollisionConfiguration* sCollisionConfig=0;
static btCollisionDispatcher* sCollisionDispatcher=0;
static btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver* sConstraintSolver=0;
static btBroadphaseInterface* sBroadphase=0;
static btDiscreteDynamicsWorld *sDynamicsWorld=0;


- (id)init
    {
    self = [super init];

    if (self==nil)
        return self;

    // init Default Timing
    //
    cycles = 2;
    clockTick = 0.016;

    // init Bullet Objects
    //
    sCollisionConfig = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
    sCollisionDispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(sCollisionConfig);
    sConstraintSolver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver;
    sBroadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();

    sDynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(sCollisionDispatcher,sBroadphase,sConstraintSolver,sCollisionConfig);
    sDynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));  // Initial Gravity of the object Space

    [PhysicsObject setDynamicsWorldPointerTo:sDynamicsWorld];

    //
    // 2.75 Increased performance by disabling motion state synchronization for static/inactive objects.
    // if that causes a problem. Uncomment the next line for backward compatibility.
    //
    // sDynamicsWorld->setSynchronizeAllMotionStates(true); 

    return self;
    }



- (void)dealloc
    {
    [self releaseConstraints];

    delete sDynamicsWorld;
    sDynamicsWorld=0;

    delete sConstraintSolver;
    sConstraintSolver=0;

    delete sCollisionDispatcher;
    sCollisionDispatcher=0;

    delete sBroadphase;
    sBroadphase=0;

    delete sCollisionConfig;
    sCollisionConfig=0;

    [super dealloc];
    }




- (void) releaseConstraints
    {
    int i;

    // remove contraints
    //
    for (i=sDynamicsWorld->getNumConstraints()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
        btTypedConstraint *joint = sDynamicsWorld->getConstraint(i);
        sDynamicsWorld->removeConstraint(joint);
        delete joint;
        }
    }



- (void) addConstraint:(btTypedConstraint *)hinge disableCollisionsBetweenLinkedBodies:(BOOL)linkcrash
    {
    if (linkcrash)
        sDynamicsWorld->addConstraint(hinge, true);
    else
        sDynamicsWorld->addConstraint(hinge, false);
    }



- (void) timeStep:(UIAccelerationValue *)accelerationValue;
    {
    if (!sDynamicsWorld)
        return;


    sDynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(accelerationValue[0], accelerationValue[1], accelerationValue[2]));


    //  Recommended values for faster systems or more simple Open/GL projects
    //
    //  cycles = 1;
    //  clockTick = 0.016f;
    //  
    sDynamicsWorld->stepSimulation( cycles*clockTick, cycles, clockTick);
    }


//
// Same as above but with NO Gravity
//
- (void) timeStep
    {
    if (!sDynamicsWorld)
        return;

    sDynamicsWorld->stepSimulation( cycles*clockTick, cycles, clockTick);
    }

@end









//
//  PhysicsObject.h
//  Created by John Carter on 4/9/09.
//
#import "BulletEngine.h"

@interface PhysicsObject : NSObject
    {
    btCollisionShape* collisionShape;
    btRigidBody *rigidBody;
    btDefaultMotionState *motionState;
    btCollisionObject *collisionObject;
    }

@property (readonly) btCollisionShape* collisionShape;
@property (readonly) btRigidBody *rigidBody;
@property (readonly) btDefaultMotionState *motionState;
@property (readonly) btCollisionObject *collisionObject;

+ (void) setDynamicsWorldPointerTo:(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld *)initSDynamicsWorld;

- (btRigidBody *) addPhysicsObject:(btCollisionShape *)newObjectShape At:(btVector3)location Tilt:(btVector3)tilt Mass:(btScalar)mass;
- (btRigidBody *) addInfinitePlane:(int)plane Shape:(btBoxShape *)worldBoxShape At:(btTransform)groundTransform Boundary:(btVector3)boundarySize;

@end




//
//  PhysicsObject.m
//  Created by John Carter on 4/9/09.
//
#import "PhysicsObject.h"


// Owned and Set by BulletEngine Object
//
static btDiscreteDynamicsWorld *sDynamicsWorld;


// Private Methods
//
@interface PhysicsObject()

@end


@implementation PhysicsObject


@synthesize collisionShape;
@synthesize rigidBody;
@synthesize motionState;
@synthesize collisionObject;




+ (void) setDynamicsWorldPointerTo:(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld *)initSDynamicsWorld
    {
    sDynamicsWorld=initSDynamicsWorld;
    }



- (void)dealloc
    {
    if (collisionShape)
        {
        delete collisionShape;
        collisionShape = 0;
        }

    if (rigidBody)
        {
        sDynamicsWorld->removeRigidBody(rigidBody);
        }

    if (motionState)
        {
        delete motionState;
        motionState = 0;
        }

    if (collisionObject)
        {
        sDynamicsWorld->removeCollisionObject( collisionObject );
        delete collisionObject;
        collisionObject = 0;
        }

    if (rigidBody)
        {
        delete rigidBody;
        rigidBody = 0;
        }

    [super dealloc];
    }



- (void) setCollisionObjectPointer
    {
    int i;
    for (i=sDynamicsWorld->getNumCollisionObjects()-1; i>=0 ;i--)
        {
        btCollisionObject* colObj = sDynamicsWorld->getCollisionObjectArray()[i];
        if (colObj)
            {
            btRigidBody* body = btRigidBody::upcast(colObj);
            if (body==rigidBody)
                {
                collisionObject = colObj;
                return;
                }
            }
        }

    collisionObject=0;

    return;
    }



- (btRigidBody *) addInfinitePlane:(int)plane Shape:(btBoxShape *)worldBoxShape At:(btTransform)groundTransform Boundary:(btVector3)boundarySize
    {
    btVector4 planeEq;

    worldBoxShape->getPlaneEquation( planeEq, plane);

    collisionShape = new btStaticPlaneShape( -planeEq, planeEq[3] );

    motionState = new btDefaultMotionState(groundTransform);

    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbInfo(btScalar(0.0),  motionState,  collisionShape,  btVector3(btScalar(0.0),btScalar(0.0),btScalar(0.0)));

    btRigidBody* objectBody = new btRigidBody(rbInfo);

    sDynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(objectBody);

    [self setCollisionObjectPointer];

    return objectBody;
    }



- (btRigidBody *) addPhysicsObject:(btCollisionShape *)newObjectShape At:(btVector3)location Tilt:(btVector3)tilt Mass:(btScalar)mass
    {
    btTransform bodyTransform;
    bodyTransform.setIdentity();
    bodyTransform.setOrigin(location);
    bodyTransform.getBasis().setEulerZYX(tilt[0],tilt[1],tilt[2]);
    btVector3 localInertia(0,0,0);

    if ( mass > btScalar(0.0))
        {
        newObjectShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass,localInertia);
        }

    motionState = new btDefaultMotionState(bodyTransform);
    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbInfo(mass,motionState,newObjectShape,localInertia);
    btRigidBody* objectBody=new btRigidBody(rbInfo);

    //
    // Prevents objects from falling asleep after being idle for a long time
    //
    if ( objectBody != nil && mass >= btScalar(0.0))
        {
        objectBody->setDeactivationTime(0.0);
        objectBody->setSleepingThresholds(0.0, 0.0);
        objectBody->activate();
        }

    //add the body to the dynamics world
    //
    sDynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(objectBody);

    [self setCollisionObjectPointer];

    return objectBody;
    }

@end







//
//  MeshObject.h
//  Created by John Carter on 4/9/09.
//
#import "PhysicsObject.h"

@interface MeshObject : PhysicsObject
    {
    btTriangleMesh *mesh;
    }

- (id) initAt:(btVector3)location Size:(btVector3)size VertexCount:(int)initVertexCount Verticies:(btVector3 *)initVertex Mass:(btScalar)mass;
- (id) initAt:(btVector3)location Size:(btVector3)size VertexCount:(int)initVertexCount Verticies:(btVector3 *)initVertex Tilt:(btVector3)tilt Mass:(btScalar)mass;

@end



//
//  MeshObject.m
//  Created by John Carter on 4/9/09.
//
#import "MeshObject.h"


// Private Methods
//
@interface MeshObject()

@end


@implementation MeshObject


- (void)dealloc
    {
    delete mesh;
    mesh=0;
    [super dealloc];
    }

- (id) initAt:(btVector3)location Size:(btVector3)size VertexCount:(int)initVertexCount Verticies:(btVector3 *)initVertex Mass:(btScalar)mass
    {
    self = [super init];

    if (self==nil)
        return self;

    mesh = new btTriangleMesh(false);

    int i;
    for ( i=0 ; i<initVertexCount; i+=3)
        {
        btVector3 v1 = btVector3( initVertex[i+0][0]*size[0], initVertex[i+0][1]*size[1], initVertex[i+0][2]*size[2]);
        btVector3 v2 = btVector3( initVertex[i+1][0]*size[0], initVertex[i+1][1]*size[1], initVertex[i+1][2]*size[2]);
        btVector3 v3 = btVector3( initVertex[i+2][0]*size[0], initVertex[i+2][1]*size[1], initVertex[i+2][2]*size[2]);
        mesh->addTriangle(v1,v2,v3);
        }

    collisionShape = new btBvhTriangleMeshShape( mesh, true );

    rigidBody = [self addPhysicsObject:(btCollisionShape *)collisionShape At:(btVector3)location Tilt:btVector3(btScalar(0.0), btScalar(0.0), btScalar(0.0)) Mass:(btScalar)mass];

    return self;
    }



- (id) initAt:(btVector3)location Size:(btVector3)size VertexCount:(int)initVertexCount Verticies:(btVector3 *)initVertex Tilt:(btVector3)tilt Mass:(btScalar)mass
    {
    self = [super init];

    if (self==nil)
        return self;

    mesh = new btTriangleMesh(false);

    int i;
    for ( i=0 ; i<initVertexCount; i+=3)
        {
        btVector3 v1 = btVector3( initVertex[i+0][0]*size[0], initVertex[i+0][1]*size[1], initVertex[i+0][2]*size[2]);
        btVector3 v2 = btVector3( initVertex[i+1][0]*size[0], initVertex[i+1][1]*size[1], initVertex[i+1][2]*size[2]);
        btVector3 v3 = btVector3( initVertex[i+2][0]*size[0], initVertex[i+2][1]*size[1], initVertex[i+2][2]*size[2]);
        mesh->addTriangle(v1,v2,v3);
        }

    collisionShape = new btBvhTriangleMeshShape( mesh, true );

    rigidBody = [self addPhysicsObject:(btCollisionShape *)collisionShape At:(btVector3)location Tilt:tilt Mass:(btScalar)mass];

    return self;
    }



@end
```